# Why does Firefox show SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN with a self-signed wildcard certificate, but other browsers do not?

Tags: ssl-certificate, firefox, wildcard, openwrt

I assigned a self signed wildcard certificate to an OpenWRT (LEDE) router LUCI (uHTTPd) system.
The CA which signed this certificate got added to all browsers as trusted certificate authoritiy.

It works fine on Internet Explorer, Edge and Chrome, but not on Firefox 58.0.2, which throws the error SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN, even when it states on the same error page that the certificate is issued for this domain.

If I issue the certificate directly for the host (no wildcard) then it works fine in FF as well.

What could cause this issue?

Comment: Could you show the cert subject information and the URL that you are requesting?

Comment: Hope this helps:
https://i.imgur.com/YldUNF0.png
https://i.imgur.com/OfKBUgb.png

Comment: Did you add the certificate in Firefox trust store as an authority?

Comment: No not the certificate, but the CA which signed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your certificate has the following "Subject Alternative Names" (SAN):

1. DNS:*.mainserver.local
2. **DNS:*.mainserver**
3. DNS:*.mgmt.ctb.co.at
4. IP:192.168.0.254
5. IP:192.168.0.9
6. IP:192.168.10.254
7. IP:192.168.11.254
8. IP:192.168.12.254
9. DNS:mgmt.ctb.co.at
10. DNS:mainserver.local

Firefox does not like entry 2, as it considers `mainserver` a TLD and **aborts** there; the following entries are **not** checked, so your `fw1.mgmt.ctb.co.at` never matches entry 3.

I solved a similar problem in our domain be re-ordering the SANs and putting all FQDNs first; you should move your entry 2 to the end.

## Firefox issues of interest

- [1489045: Wildcard certificate not working properly using enterprise roots](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1489045)
- [1196364: Proper handling for wildcard certificates for all tlds](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1196364)
- [1757758: consider having mozilla::pkix ignore invalid entries in subjectAlternativeNames](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1757758)
- [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/list/)